# Computing another graph with edges of exactly length l from an unweighted, undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, runtime, breadth-first-search

What is a method of making another graph featuring vertices that can be only gotten to with an edge length of l from every vertex `V` in the original unweighted (assume edges of length 1) and undirected graph `G=(V,E)`. I came up with a solution that just searches through each branch from each `V` using depth-first search on each vertex until I found all the vertices of path length l from each vertex. This gives a runtime of `O(V^(l+1))` so of course, this is not the optimal solution. Can anyone help me find a better solution with a better asymptotic runtime?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understood your problem correctly, but it sounds like you should be able to use matrix exponentiation by squaring to calculate the `l`th power of the adjacency matrix for the graph (which gives you the paths of length `l`) in `O(V^3 log l)` time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm that uses a matrix representation (as @Hammar suggested) but finishes in `O(V^3)` regardless of `l`. Instead of `l` matrix exponentiations, you determine all distances by sequentially inserting nodes and determining the effect on the shortest paths.